# Error: "ReplaceAll: ... is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing." when solving a root

Tags: equation-solving, functions, warning-messages, list-manipulation, modeling

I have this code:

```
\[Alpha]=0.86;
\[Beta]=0.6;
g=0.0005;
p[x_,y_,t_,ta_,f_,fa_,u_]:=(((\[Alpha]^\[Alpha])((1-\[Alpha])^(1-\[Alpha])) (y-(t+ta)*x-(f+fa)))/u)^(1/(1-\[Alpha]));
r[x_,y_,t_,ta_,f_,fa_,u_]:=(p[x,y,t,ta,f,fa,u](g))((1/(p[x,y,t,ta,f,fa,u](\[Beta])(g)))^(\[Beta]/(\[Beta]-1)))-1((1/(p[x,y,t,ta,f,fa,u](\[Beta])(g)))^(1/(\[Beta]-1)));

Table[
 
 y = 70000;
 t = 600;
 f = 0;
 ta = 0;
 fa = 0;
 ra = 45000;
 
 Lu[u_] := (solution = 
    FindRoot[{r[x, y, t, ta, f, fa, u] - ra == 0}, {xbar, 10}, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 1]; xbar /. solution);]
```

There is more code after this inside the table function, but the FindRoot part gives me this error:

"ReplaceAll::reps: {FindRoot[{r[x,y,t,ta,f,fa,3000]-ra==0},{xbar,10},AccuracyGoal->1]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing."

Any help on solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: \[Alpha] is not defined.

Comment: Instead of `Lu[u_]...` try just `FindRoot[{r[x,y,t,ta,f,fa,u]-ra==0},{xbar,10},AccuracyGoal->1]` with a value for `u` that makes this fail substituted in there. Exactly what does the result of that look like? Is that something in exactly the correct form that will make sense when you try to use that with /. ? The more usual form is `Lu[u_]:=xbar/.FindRoot[...]` Is there a good reason you are not doing that?

Comment: If I just write that, it treats it as text

Comment: @Bill There is a good reason, becayse Lu[u_] is being used in another function later on

Comment: I am trying to tell you how to find and fix the error you are getting so you can later get the solution you want. You reposted the same question and people told you to do the same thing that I did.